# Is there any in-universe canon mention of Princess Leia's cinammon bun hairstyle?

Tags: star-wars

It's an iconic image, yet no one else in the galaxy seems to wear their hair like that. In the numerous expanded universe sources, does the style receive a name?

Comment: To be fair, it might have been very popular on Alderaan at the time...

Comment: Why the downvotes? Not a great question, but not an awful one. The hairstyle, on the other hand, has its benefits. Anyone who has ever taken a girl home after a convention knows what I mean.

Comment: The queen of the Naboobians wears her hair the same way...http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9858/leia060.jpg

Comment: Seriously people. If you downvote, at least leave a comment and say why, please.

Comment: +1 because some folks think downvotes are like hand grenades. They pull the pin and run.

Comment: @user14111 If you hover over the upvote and downvote arrows, a tooltip appears that tells you what they're for: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" and "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  Seems like a lot of people miss that...

Comment: @user14111 So yeah, interesting _and_ those other things.  I'd meant that people seem to skip over those other things when they upvote.  (And, a "cinnamon bun" is a type of food that vaguely resembles one of Leia's hair-buns.  I don't think it's a very close match, though - other than being mostly circular, their shape doesn't seem to have anything in common.)

Comment: So wait - is the question "What is the in-universe name of Leia's hairstyle" or is it "Was there any indication that others wear their hair like that"?  The marked answer seems to answer the second, not sure anyone can answer the first.

Comment: @joshbirk - That sounds like a challenge dammit!"

Comment: I'd say so - you'll need to find a direct reference to a hairstyle which was popular on a now destroyed planet which is distinctly a name for the style, not a quip or a joke.  Movies are out.  Comics too, probably.  Best bet is a novelization describing Leia.

Comment: Given that Star Wars takes place in a galaxy far, far away with very different cultures, personally I think it would have been cool to see Han Solo with the cinnamon buns and Leia with the mullet. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It's an iconic image, yet no one else in the galaxy seems to wear their hair like that.

Her mother wore a very similar style (though Leia probably didn't know that).

In *Attack of the Clones*, Padme wears a style very reminiscent, though more ornate.

[image: padme 1]

Then when she lands for a meeting in *Revenge of the Sith*, she wears something almost identical to the buns Leia later wears.

[image: padme 2]

To my knowledge/recollection, there was no particular name for the hair style.

Regarding this particular style, [Wookieepedia mentions](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hair)

> A popular hairstyle among Human females consisted in coiling the hair in twin buns. Throughout history, many famous women were known to sport their hair in this fashion, including Liana Merian, Padmé Amidala, Delva Racine, and Leia Organa.

[Liana Merian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Liana_Merian) was an aide to the senator from Alderaan. Her scene was cut from the final version of The Phantom Menace, but she wore a very similar style.

[image: Liana]

[Delva Racine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Delva_Racine) was a fashion designer who appears in the the opera scene of Revenge of the Sith.

[image: delva]

Both images of Padme are from the book [*Dressing a Galaxy*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0810965674). I believe the images of Liana and Delva were from promotional materials released later.

Comment: The prequels aren't much help. Her hair is described in the concept art notes as 'leia buns'

Comment: That may be the description in the notes, but it clearly dispels the notion that "no one else in the galaxy seems to wear their hair like that", as there are three other Canon characters who wear their hair in a very similar way (two G-canon, one c-canon).

Comment: That's very true, but out of universe it's clear that she's wearing them as a retcon homage to the original series

Comment: Retcon or not, they're canon instances of it. The question wasn't regarding the origin of the hairstyle.

Comment: Delva Racine outfit --- priceless!

Comment: No, the name of the game was 'What's it called?' Unfortunately the prequels are no help because theyjust reference the earlier films.

Comment: It's a two-part question, Richard.  "Is there any in-universe canon mention of Princess Leia's cinammon bun hairstyle?" Yes. Three other times. "Does the style in the HUNDREDS of expanded universe sources, receive a name?" No, not based on my research. What part do you not understand?

Comment: My only problem with this answer is that I find it difficult to believe a fashion designer would wear a mask with that nose.... #yesiamkidding

Comment: @phantom42 - Erm, because in the prequel scripts (OOU) it's called "leia buns" yet they can't possibly be called that in-universe she hasn't been born yet.

Comment: I never said it was called that in-universe or out-of-universe. I said in my answer that I found no particular name for the hairstyle. The fact that there is no name for it, or that it is referred to as "Leia Buns" in concept notes means ZERO in determining whether or not they exist elsewhere in canon.

Answer (score 9):

In-universe, I've been unable to locate the name of the hairstyle. Both Padme and her maid wear similar styles in the prequel films but the concept art describes them as "Leia Buns" which is clearly no help.

[image: Leia Buns] [image: Padme Buns]

Out of universe, there's a [quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Leia#%22Cinnamon_buns%22_hairstyle) from George Lucas describing the hairstyle created by professional stylist Pat McDermott (from original concept art by Ralph Mcquarrie) as

> "a kind of Southwestern Pancho Villa woman revolutionary look, which
>   is what that is. The buns are basically from turn-of-the-century
>   Mexico."

[image: Leia Buns] [image: Panco Woman]

[image: Concept Art]

Within the film universe, there's certain no mention of her 'cinnamon bun' hairstyle but there is a line in the [*Empire Strikes Back* script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) describing her later hairstyle as "*braided across her head in a Nordic fashion*".

[image: Leia Hoth Hair]